# A noun for “phony” or an alternative to "phoniness"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I visited some famous tourist hotspots in a country where I enjoyed some beautiful sceneries. However, once we were told some trees planted there were actually fake (the trees were carefully sculpted to appear natural), we felt betrayed by the **__**?

Comment: Artificiality?...

Comment: The tree is trunky = the trunk of the tree. The trees are phoney = the _phone_ of the trees, obviously. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps I'm nit-picking a bit here (Then again, this seems to be an appropriate place for it). Shouldn't this question state that it's looking for an _abstract noun_? (And be tagged as such)

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/phony

Comment: I recommend _artifice_ because it has a range of meanings that cumulatively capture the cleverness and fakery of the designers of the ersatz trees. From _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003): "**artifice 1a:** clever or artful skill: INGENUITY **b:** an ingenious device or expedient **2a:** an artful stratagem: TRICK **b:** false or insincere behavior." You can feel betrayed by both the ingenuity and the trick.

Answer (score 15):

I would feel betrayed by the *deception.*

Answer (score 10):

*Fraud* sounds like a good fit for your example of the fake trees. It matches one of the definitions from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraud) very well:

> a copy of something that is meant to look like the real thing in order to trick people

Answer (score 4):

*artificiality*, *artificialness*, *fakeness*, *imitation*, *bogusness*, *bogosity*, *falseness*, *ersatzness*, *dumminess*,...

Look up synonyms for *bogus*, and then adapt to get nouns...

Answer (score 3):

*Ersatz* is useful in this context.   From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ersatz#Adjective), *ersatz* means “Made in imitation; artificial, especially of an inferior quality”.  Eg,  “We felt betrayed because the palm trees were ersatz”.

Synonyms include *artificial, faux, imitation, knock off*.

*Edit:* *Ersatz* is of course an adjective rather than a noun.  In terms of nouns, previously-suggested  *deception* perhaps has the best fit in the example sentence,  “We felt betrayed by the ____”.  Terms like *sham* and *bogosity* have more-negative connotations than are warranted, because the question clearly says  “the trees were carefully sculpted to appear natural”.  The problem is not the *appearance* of the fake trees, but rather the engendered feeling that a confidence trick has been played.  Knowing a deception's been made makes the scenery less believable.  One might then fill in the blank with *unbelievability*, or perhaps with a longer phrase like  “the *incongruity* or *shabbiness* or *unreality* of trying to improve on nature”.

Comment: Interesting. In its German origin, "Ersatz" basically just means replacement. It doesn't necessarily mean that it's inferior. Looks like it was adopted into English with a more narrow definition.

Comment: But this is still an adjective, not a noun.   You can't say "we bought an ersatz".   Or, if you do say that, I say "An ersatz what?"

Comment: The Wiktionary page you linked also lists it as a noun: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ersatz#Noun.

Comment: Interesting to note: in German `Ersatz` is only a noun and can't be used as an adjective (although there are compound adjectives like `ersatzlos` = 'without substitution' or `ersatzweise` = 'as a substitute').

Answer (score 3):

Sham fits the requirement pretty well.

From Google search:

Sham

*Noun*

1. a thing that is not what it is purported to be.

"the proposed legislation is a farce and a sham"

Answer (score 3):

"fake" could also be used as a noun and thus "fakes".

Source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fake

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me. It's not the fake trees that are offensive, *per se*, but rather the attitude of the person that decided to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with something more than a single word. Perhaps something more along the lines of "We felt betrayed by the subterfuge of using artificial trees instead of real and natural surroundings." Alternatively instead of subterfuge: fraud, deceit, dishonesty or deception.

Also, in regards to  Reto Koradi's comment above in reply to jwpat's suggestion of 'ersatz'. When used in English, is it very common for the speaker/writer to intend to impress a sense of a lower quality substitute. And has long been used in this manner.

Comment: I didn't mean to question jwpat's definition of "ersatz". I hope my comment didn't sound like I doubted it. In fact I confirmed it with a different dictionary. I just thought it was interesting that the word was adopted with a more restricted meaning. For example, in German, the word "Ersatzteil" means "spare part". If I buy a spare part for my car at a dealership, I expect it to be absolutely identical to the original part that my car came with.

Comment: Extending it out to a full sentence is unnecessarily redundant. You're effectively advocating "However, once we were told some trees planted there were actually fake (the trees were carefully sculpted to appear natural), we felt betrayed by the subterfuge of using artificial trees instead of real and natural surroundings." There's no need to describe the subterfuge twice.

Comment: Also, "fraud" is more appropriate than "fraudulence". "Fraudulence" is the tendency to commit fraud or the result of the fraud; here, we're talking about the fraud itself.

Answer (score 1):

The specific quality by which you feel betrayed here, I think, is *lack of authenticity*. If you want a single word, then the slightly-clunky *inauthenticity* would work.

Especially when traveling, it seems like we're all in search of a truly "authentic" local experience, and this is exactly what's lacking at overdone tourist hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

> However, once we were told some trees planted there were actually fake
>   , we felt betrayed by the *[**scam**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scam)* (or *[hoax](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoax)*).

A *scam* is a devious scheme set up in order to cheat people, usually out of money. In this context it fits because the OP was part of a group of *paying* tourists. As a tourist one hopes to witness first hand the natural (and possibly unspoilt) splendours of a country. The tourist is but a client who pays a fee to the tourist agency, tourist guide/tour guide etc. and in exchange expects not to be lied to. This fee includes visiting the area's *natural* and *authentic* scenery.

Once established that some of the trees are fake, one could also call the setup, a **hoax**, which Merriam_Webster defines as, *an act that is meant to trick or deceive people.*

Answer (score 0):

Simulacrum? Might not carry the 'disappointment' that you were looking for though....

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacrum

Answer (score -2):

**Faux** palm trees can be especially disturbing when you tap them and hear a metallic ringing rather than a woody thud.

[From Oxford dictionary:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/faux)

> Made in imitation; artificial:
>
> Not genuine; fake or false

Comment: The word itself is a good fit, but the asker was looking for a **noun**, and _faux_ suffers from the same drawback as _phoney_ in that _fauxness_ is quite inelegant as nouns go.